# Delegates vs Calling of Functions

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Can someone explain why I would do this code this way?
I Have a small grasp of delegates but don't understand the advantages
Can some one try and help explain what I am doing here. I am very new to classes and delegates. Just need some help.
Here is my delegate code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click
        Dim NewCompare As New Compare
        NewCompare.Num1 = 3
        NewCompare.Num2 = 2

        NewCompare.CheckCompare(AddressOf GreaterThan)
        NewCompare.CheckCompare(AddressOf SmallerThan)
    End Sub

    Function GreaterThan(Num1 As Integer, Num2 As Integer) As Boolean
        Return Num1 > Num2
    End Function

    Function SmallerThan(Num1 As Integer, Num2 As Integer) As Boolean
        Return Num1 < Num2
    End Function
End Class

Class Compare
    Property Num1 As Integer
    Property Num2 As Integer

    Delegate Function CompareValues(Num1 As Integer, Num2 As Integer) As Boolean

    Public Sub CheckCompare(compare As CompareValues)
        If compare(_Num1, _Num2) Then
            MsgBox(_Num1)
        Else
            MsgBox(_Num2)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This question will probably be closed as too broad.  The short answer is that for this specific example, in isolation, there is no benefit to using delegates in this way.  In some cases, however, you want to be able to have a user supply a method of implementing a particular type of operation.  In this case, the user has the flexibility to inject any sort of comparison to the class.  This particular class is not sufficiently complex to illustrate the benifits to such an approach, but in other situations it may be rather more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, "the essential idea" of "delegation" is simply: *"identify Someone Else that you can ask."*

In this example, the `Compare` class exists to "compare two objects."  But you've said that it is to *delegate* that responsibility to some other function that is not a part of its own definition.  Furthermore, you specify exactly what an acceptable "delegate function" must look like.

The `Delegate Function` declaration specifies what that delegate must look like. *"An acceptable delegate must return a `Boolean`, and it must accept (exactly ...) two `Integer` parameters."*  The language ensures, at compile-time, that this is so.

In your two, separate, calls to the `CheckCompare` method of the `Compare` class, you provide separate references to two functions, `GreaterThan` and `LessThan`, both of which are conformant to the strictures set out in the `Delegate Function` declaration.  Therefore, the language permits them to be used in the calls.  And, as instructed, the `CheckCompare` method invokes the delegate-function that it has been given, when told to do so.

It does not know (but, it does not care) exactly *which* delegate it is. The language ensures that "an acceptable delegate" has been provided, and all *this* method needs to do, is to call "it."